# Incrementing the value of a hashmap java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hash map of places:

```
HashMap <String, Integer> places = new HashMap <String, Integer>();
places.put("London",0);
places.put("Paris",0);
places.put("dublin",0);
```

In this places I have a key of places and a value of how many times that place occurs in a text.

Say I have a texts:

1. `iloveLondon`
2. `IamforLondon`
3. `allaboutParis`

Which are also stored in a hashmap:

```
 HashMap <String, Integer> text = new HashMap <String, Integer>();
```

I have a conditional statement to check if the place is in the text (where capitals and lower case is ignored:

```
for (String p: places):
{
   for(String t : text):
      if t.tolowercase().contains(p.tolowercase())
      {
        //then i would like to increment the value for places of the places hashmap
      }
}
```

In this example, the output should be:
London, 2
Paris, 1
Dublin, 0

Ive got everything, except outputting the values and incrementing it, any suggestions?

Comment: Replace the value with the value plus one.

Comment: ... or use a mutable integer class as value (JDK brings `AtomicInt` e.g.).

Comment: which value? should i replace

Comment: You should replace the value that corresponds to the key.

Comment: How, this is what i am trying to do

Comment: You can replace (`put(..)` will overwrite) entries in a `Map`. See the javadoc

Comment: Everything you need to know is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To increment a value all you need to do is:

```
places.put("London",places.get("London")+1);
```

If the map does not contain "London" then the get will return a null, to handle that case you need to do:

```
Integer value = places.get("London");
if (value == null) {
   value = 1;
} else {
   value += 1;
}

places.put("London", value);
```

Comment: Added some info on that.

Comment: If you try and get a value from a hashmap that doesn't exist in the hashmap then the `get()` returns null.

Comment: @Pro-grammer - Saying you got a null pointer exception, and not identifying *which* pointer was null, is a sign of sheer laziness.